# Double nested JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have one top-level schema
`content.json`

```json
{
    "title": "Program content schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/program",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tools": {
                    "$ref": "/schemas/tool"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which references another schema, `tool.json`

```json
{
  "title": "Tool information schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/tool",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "nodeInformation": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "$ref": "/schemas/gui"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and that references another schema, `gui.json`

```json
{
    "title": "Gui schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/gui",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "children": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the data itself

```json
{
    "content": {
        "id": "",
        "tools": {
            "nodeInformation": {
                "name": "Dummy Name",
                "description": "Tool Description"
            },
            "active": "true",
            "children": []
        }
    }
}
```

If I introduce errors in the `gui` schema, they are not recognized. For example, the following data should have been recognized as an error

```json
"active": "true"
```

because the schema defines it as

```json
"active": {
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

Comment: You have a mistake inside `tool.json`, `properties.nodeInformation.properties.$ref` needs to be an object. Also, it looks like your are trying to use a reference there, but json schema only allows references at places where a schema is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tool` schema needs an `allOf` to compose your defined schemas

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Program content schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/program",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tools": {
                    "$ref": "/schemas/tool"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Tool information schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/tool",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "nodeInformation": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$ref": "/schemas/gui"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Gui schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/gui",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "children": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    }
}
```